# String end with substring

Tags: php, string, http, url, browser

I want to check if string is end with substring. To check if a file path location is in a given url

The Original url is: 
[image]

This is how the browser is encoded it :

http://a13815-tmp.s213.upress.link/%D7%94%D7%9E%D7%95%D7%A6%D7%A8%D7%99%D7%9D-%D7%A9%D7%9C%D7%A0%D7%95/%D7%A9%D7%A7%D7%99%D7%95%D7%AA-%D7%A4%D7%9C%D7%A1%D7%98%D7%99%D7%A7/

Now in my system a user can put a url path and if the Original url is ended with the url path then... Do something.

So if the url path is : **המוצרים/**

Then the function will return true.

The thing is that the strings that i work with them are not a english string. So i need to work with urlencode string. (This is how the browser send me the url)

So the url is :
http://a13815-tmp.s213.upress.link/%D7%94%D7%9E%D7%95%D7%A6%D7%A8%D7%99%D7%9D-%D7%A9%D7%9C%D7%A0%D7%95/%D7%A9%D7%A7%D7%99%D7%95%D7%AA-%D7%A4%D7%9C%D7%A1%D7%98%D7%99%D7%A7/

the substring is (after urlencode): 
%d7%94%d7%9e%d7%95%d7%a6%d7%a8%d7%99%d7%9d%2f

it's doesn't work. becouse the browser reverse the order of the url path. and also the '/' location.

So how i can deal with it?

I use the next function in order to check if string ends with substring and it's work fine with english language url

```
function matching_ends($s1,$s2){
return substr($s1, -strlen($s2)) == $s2 ? "true" : "false";}
```

Comment: Is the original language wrote right to left by any chance?

Comment: Hebrew generally is right to left

Comment: Yes. Hebrew is right to left